# Generating Padovan Sequence

Tags: python

The Padovan sequence is governed by the relationship P(n+1) = P(n-1) + P(n-2), for n is a
non-negative integer, where P(0) = P(1) = P(2) = 1. So, for instance, P(3) = 2, P(4) = 2, and
P (5) = 3, and so on.

I want to write a Python program Pad(n) that generates the sequence P(0), P(1), ..., P(n - 1).

This is what I have this far, but it only produces a list with the ith number replicated up to the largest number in the sequence:

```
def ith(n):

    first, sec, third, fourth = 1, 1, 1, 1
    for i in range(3, n+1):
        fourth = first + sec
        first = sec
        sec = third
        third = fourth

    return fourth



def pad(n):
    pad = ith(n)
    lst = []
    for i in range(n):
        lst.append(pad)

    return lst
```

I want it to produce this as an output:

```
>>> Pad(6)
>>>[1,1,1,2,2,3]
```

Currently my code only produces:

```
>>>[4,4,4,4,4,4]
```

I now that I append the ith value ith number of times to the list, but I dont know how to append each number in series up to and including the value for the last number. Pad(6) yields 4 since this is all the previous relationships put together.

Sorry for my bad description and formulating of the problem.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation?

Comment: This looks like a great candidate for a recursive function. The recurrence relation is given on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence).

Comment: I know, but Im too stupid to use the recursive function on this problem. Also edited the identation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a two minor errors in your `pad()` function.

First you should be calling the `ith()` function *inside* the loop (also don't name the variable `pad` as that's the name of the function and it can cause problems).

Secondly, you are calling `ith(n)` inside the loop when you should be calling `ith(i)`. This is the reason that you were always getting the same number- the argument to `ith()` was not changing inside the loop.

A fixed version of your `pad()` function would be:

```
def pad(n):
    lst = []
    for i in range(n):
        val = ith(i)
        lst.append(val)

    return lst
```

You can verify that this indeed produces the correct output of `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]` for `pad(6)`.

---

**More efficient non-recursive method**

Now, while your method works, it's also very inefficient. You are calling the `ith()` function for every value in `range(n)` which recomputes the entire sequence from the beginning *each* time.

A better way would be to store the intermediate results in a list, rather than by calling a function to get the `ith()` value.

Here is an example of a better way:

```
def pad2(n):
    lst = [1, 1, 1]  # initialize the list to the first three values in the sequence
    for i in range(3,n):
        lst.append(lst[i-2] + lst[i-3])  # use already computed values!
    # slice the list to only return first n values (to handle case of n <= 3)
    return lst[:n]
```

**Recursive method**

As seen on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence), the recurrence relation shows us that `pad(n) = pad(n-2) + pad(n-3)`.

Use this as the starting point for a recursive function: `return pad(n-2) + pad(n-3)`

This is *almost* everything you need, except we have to define the starting values for the sequence. So just return `1` if `n < 3`, otherwise use the recurrence relation:

```
def pad_recursive(n):
    if n < 3:
        return 1
    else:
        return pad_recursive(n-2) + pad_recursive(n-3)
```

Then you can get the first `n` values in the sequence via list comprehension:

```
print([pad_recursive(n) for n in range(6)])
#[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

But this suffers from the same drawback as your original function as it computes the entire sequence from scratch in each iteration.